# Installing pybluez using pip3

Tags: python, installation, pybluez

i am trying to install pybluez package using pip3. but i always get the following error, when I write to terminal "pip3 install pybluez"

> Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/_r/vshyh8x51h59xl0nks7jtz280000gn/T/pip-build-2gek1vzy/pybluez/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_r/vshyh8x51h59xl0nks7jtz280000gn/T/pip-jiy18qdr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_r/vshyh8x51h59xl0nks7jtz280000gn/T/pip-build-2gek1vzy/pybluez/

So far I have only found that upgrading the 'setuptools' might help, but it did not. I have also installed xcode to my mac. So does anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu system, you might want to try using:

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetoothdev
```